# How do I paginate a `DataGridView` to only show X rows at a time for large amounts of data?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, pagination

I've been searching, but have not found a solution for this.

I have `DataGridView` that is bound to hundreds or thousands of rows.

How do I paginate the `DataGridView` to only show let's say 50 rows at a time?

Comment: which 50 do you want?  the newest, oldest, between a certain date range?  when you decide that, make it a WHERE clause in your SQL

Comment: i will go for the newest

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to solve? `cut the informations` is abstract and thousands of rows is not a lot of data for the DGV to handle.  You can use ORDER BY to arrange the data displayed and WHERE clauses to restrict the data set as you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill your datagrid view and then this code could run after you sort your columns so only the top 50 rows are shown and the rest are hidden
You would run this routine when the datagrid is filled as well

```
 Private Sub dataGridView1_Sorted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dataGridView1.Sorted

        Dim j As Integer = 1
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView1.Rows
            If j <= 50 Then
                row.Visible = True
            Else
                row.Visible = False
            End If
            j += 1
        Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Why load your datagrid woth records that will never be shown?

Comment: @equisde No idea. The question was `if i will be having datagridview with hundreds or thousands information stored on this . how can i cut the given informations let we said 50 rows only will be visible in datagrid.` Does what was asked

Comment: @pt000 you're right. Although not the optimal way, think that helped our friend

Comment: @equisde yes ? best way

Comment: @Mark My suggestion: Do not load the dataGridView with data that you don't need to show and then hide. Use a WHERE clause to discard non-desired records.

Comment: Or use `SELECT TOP 50` and `ORDER BY` statements to choose your top 50 records based on the order in a column